# Fiddler certificate not working, getting certificate invalid errors when running

Tags: ssl-certificate, fiddler

I am recently starting to have fiddler4 problems with certificates.  When I attempt to access bing.com and I have fiddler running to capture the traffic I am getting error pages like this:

> Your connection is not private
>
> Attackers might be trying to steal your information from www.bing.com
>   (for example, passwords, messages, or credit cards).
>   NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID
>
> Automatically send some system information and page content to Google
>   to help detect dangerous apps and sites. Privacy policy

I have followed instructions [here](http://www.fiddlerbook.com/fiddler/help/httpsdecryption.asp) to setup certificate on fiddler but continue to have problems.

Comment: Did you found any fixes to this?

Comment: It's been a while, as I remember I actually had to setup a certificate in fiddler and use an https url to access the site.  I'm afraid I don't remember the details and I'm not working with fiddler recently!

Comment: actually I am able to capture https traffic after setting up fiddler root certificate on phone as well as on system where I am running fiddler but for some domain it is not working.